GiveWP - Error: Your access token has expired. Please request a new one
I using this plugin to donation form https://givewp.com/
We’re noticing some donors are receiving an error message when they attempt to donate. I’m aware this can be related to the donor’s cache; however, we had one donor who had never accessed the site before and received the error. Would it be possible to turn this error message off?

